# How the program has control with the break statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.x

Could anybody explain this program and output of this? I am having doubt at if statement. I'm not able to understand how break statement works in this:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        print n, 'is a prime number'
```

Output:

```
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

Comment: Please format the code and output. And post real code without the ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement leaves the loop without entering the `else` clause.  If the loop terminates without reaching the `break`, the `else` clause will be entered.  In other words, the loop searches for a possible divisor; if it finds one it prints it and leaves the loop using `break`.  If no divisor is found, the for loop terminates "normally" and thus enters the `else` clause (in which it then prints that it has found a prime).

Answer (score 2):

I'll add some comments:

```
for n in range(2, 10): #Loops from 2 to 9, inclusive. Call this Loop A.
    for x in range(2, n): #Loops from 2 to n-1, inclusive. Call this Loop B.
        if n % x == 0: #If n is divisible by x, execute the indented code
            print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x #print the discovered factorization
            break #Break out of loop B, skipping the "else" statement
    else: #If the loop terminates naturally (without a break) this will be executed
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        print n, 'is a prime number'
```

Comment: Thanks GrantS. This really helped me understand what was taking place.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this program is trying to identify prime numbers. A prime number, has no factors (i.e. when you divide a prime number by x, there is always a remainder), other than 1 (obviously!) and itself. So, we need to test every number from 2 (i.e. not 1) up to the number before our test to see if it is a factor of our test number.

The test that is running, steps through like this:

```
# S1 is a set of numbers, and we want to identify the prime numbers within it.
S1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# test a whether n is PRIME:
for n in S1:
    # if n / x has no remainder, then it is not prime
    for x in range(2, n):
        if...
            I have NO REMAINDER, then x is a factor of n, and n is not prime
            -----> can "BREAK" out of test, because n is clearly not PRIME
            --> move on to next n, and test it
        else:
            test next x against n
            if we find NO FACTORS, then n is PRIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Break leaves the inner most loop directly and goes to the next step of the outer for loop.