# break and continue Statements

Tags: python, for-loop, range, break

So I just started learnig how to code and I've been studying from the guide on the official python website and I came across this subject but I don't quite understand how this code works can someone explain it to me please?

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals' , x, '*' , n//x)
            break
    else:
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

This loop searches for prime numbers

Comment: This answer explains it https://stackoverflow.com/a/16451661/4727702

Comment: It is nested looping (for)
if n modules x == 0 , mean even number, then the inner loop will break (terminated) and continue to the new loop 
else , will execute if the condition "if" in loop not met (n is odd)
print(n, 'equals' , x, '*' , n//x) , show the output to terminal, console